# Node.js as WebService for sending information

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, web-services

can you tell me if i can use Node.js to collect data from one application and send it to another application better said use it as a WebService?

We have enterprise application in Java and I want to collect data on form (not DB) and send it to another application.

Any example of that code would be appreciated. I can build API to go GET it from and POST it in but I am lost when collecting data and sending it.

[Simple architecture of communication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjfdd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perfectly build a webservice with NodeJS. It is often used for this purpose, as an content aggregation service.

For building your own REST services you should have a look at **expressjs**. It is widely used and tons of examples can be found on the internet.

For firing your own web requests, you can use the build-in http/s packages or use a custom one like **request** which is also used on a large scale.

If I may give you one last advice; avoid callbacks and use a promise library instead like for example **Q** which does an excellent job. Keeps the code more readable and maintainable.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Nico on your advice.